# Precedence inside While loop

Tags: c, while-loop

I wrote a program for linked list which accepts value in ascending order. I have a while loop inside the program regarding which I have a question. I'm not entering the full code, it's just the modular function for inserting in ascending order. Here, x is taken as input from user and head node is passed into the function. Now, In while loop, if I exchange the conditions, i.e. keep "x > temp->next->data" in front and move "temp->next != NULL" behind, then, I'm getting an error if my input sequence is like (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) i.e. already in ascending order.

```
 list *insert(list *head, int x)
 {
    list *temp = head, *prev = temp, *temp2 = create();
    temp2->data = x;
    if(head == NULL || x < head->data)
    {
        temp2->next = head;
        head = temp2;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp->next != NULL && x > temp->next->data) //while(x > temp->next->data && temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp2->next = temp->next;
        temp->next = temp2;
    }
    return head;
 }
```

The way I think it is, when I enter 1, it goes to if statement(considering head is empty initially) and 1 is added to list. Then, when I enter 2 and if it checks the condition, temp->next is NULL due to only one element in list, and, NULL->data will give an error. But, it works if the conditions are according to the program above. Is it that while loop gives precedence to the conditions within itself?

Comment: `&&` is short-circuiting. I.e. if in `(a && b)` `a` is `false`, then `b` won't be evaluated.

Comment: Remember that the logical operators `||` and `&&` uses [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: If `temp->next` is `NULL` then calling `temp->next->data` will result in error. You have to check if `temp->next` is `NULL` before trying to access `temp->next->data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is not related specifically to `while` but to the logical AND operator `&&`.

The `&&` operator is a "short-circuit" operator.  This means that if the result of the operand can be determined solely by evaluating the left operand, then the right operand is not evaluated at all.

In this specific case that's a good thing.  In the event that `temp->next` is NULL, the left operand of `&&` is false so we know that the result of the operator is false and therefore it is not necessary to evaluate `x > temp->next->data`

If however you were to switch the operands of `&&`:

```
x > temp->next->data && temp->next != NULL
```

Then `temp->next->data` gets evaluated without checking if `temp-next` is NULL.  This opens up the possibility of dereferencing a NULL pointer which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).